# Special case of updating a column with not null and unique constraints in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, unique-constraint

This is a toy example that illustrates a real problem in PostgreSQL.  The below examples are using a PostgreSQL 8.4.3 server, but I suspect other versions have the same problem.

Given the following table:

```
=> create table tmp_foo (foo boolean not null unique, bar boolean not null unique);
=> insert into tmp_foo (foo, bar) values (true, true), (false, false);
=> select * from tmp_foo;
 foo | bar 
-----+-----
 t   | t
 f   | f
```

can the table be modified to look like this:

```
=> select * from tmp_foo;
 foo | bar 
-----+-----
 t   | f
 f   | t
```

without deleting rows or modifying the table schema?  This:

```
=> update tmp_foo set bar = not bar;
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tmp_foo_bar_key"
```

does not work.

If deletes are allowed, this:

```
=> create temp table tmp_foo_2 as select * from tmp_foo;
=> update tmp_foo_2 set bar = not bar;
=> delete from tmp_foo;
=> insert into tmp_foo select * from tmp_foo_2;
```

works.  It is not the simplest solution for this example, but it is easily generalizable to more complex examples.

Comment: It's an interesting problem, but I don't understand why you don't want a delete in there.  You've created a very, er, constrained set of constraints.  What's the larger problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this requires deferrable unique constraints.

We have as many rows as possible unique values in each column.  So to mutate any row, either some rows must temporarily violate a unique constraint, or some row(s) must be deleted to avoid violating the constraint.  Deferrable unique constraints let us do the former -- temporary violation (inside a transaction).

If you follow this far, and it sounds right, then the answer to your question depends on the Postgres version.

Postgres up to 8.4 only [allows deferral of foreign key constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-set-constraints.html).  The corollary is that unique constraints cannot be deferred.

Postgres 9.0 betas theoretically offer deferrable unique constraints.  I haven't tried it myself, but this feature has been a long time coming, so I'd bet they got it right when they decided to implement it.

Here are two morsels of relevant documentation on 9.0's [unique indices](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/index-unique-checks.html) and [`SET CONSTRAINTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-set-constraints.html).  As you can see in the latter link, unique constraints are explicitly listed as supported for deferral via `SET CONSTRAINTS` in the 9.0 documentation.  I haven't explored this new feature yet and I can't guarantee that the semantics are exactly what you need.  But it seems like just the thing.